# HP Pavilion G7-2325 notebook drivers

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, laptop, drivers, hp-pavilion

I just bought a brand new HP Pavilion G7-2325 Notebook, removed Windows 8 and installed Windows 7. On HP's [website](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=5363888&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us) they only offer Windows 8 drivers. The problem is that not all of the Windows 8 drivers are compatible with Windows 7.

I'm still missing a working video card driver that support Aero along with an SM Bus Controller driver and USB Controller drivers. What can I do to fix this? Not having Windows 7 drivers on their site is ludicrous!

Comment: Ludicrous?  Why would they support an old OS that isnt sold with that laptop, when the current OS has been out for a year?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem. HP's 'drivers' are usually just repackaged Intel or AMD.

If you go to Device Manager, go to the properties of each of your 'unknown' devices (yellow explamation mark.

Then go to the Details tab. Drop down the combo and select 'Hardware Ids'

You will see a list of mumbo jumbo numbers. This information is gold.

VEN_8086 means the device is Intel. But what you want is the SUBSYS number.

Search for it on google, and you'll easily find what needs to be downloaded.

Some downloads, like the appropriate Intel Chipsets download, should knock out the USB and SM Bus (off the top of my head)

Comment: Suprising how hard this trick is to come by :)